# Creating status item - icon shows up, menu doesn't

Tags: cocoa, statusbar, nsstatusitem, nsapplication

In a document-based project I am trying to create a status menu. I have a singleton class that builds the status bar, and I am initiating it from an application delegate, as you can see. When I run this, I get no errors, but only an image of the status bar, but no menu drops down. I created the menu in IB. What am I messing up?

### Delegate

```
#import "KBAppDelegate.h"
#import "KBStatusMenu.h"

@implementation KBAppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    KBStatusMenu *aStatusItem = [[KBStatusMenu alloc] init];
    aStatusItem = [[KBStatusMenu instance] buildStatusItem];
}
@end
```

### .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KBStatusMenu : NSObject 
{
    NSStatusItem *myStatusItem;
    NSImage *statusImage;
    IBOutlet NSMenu *myStatusMenu;
}

+ (KBStatusMenu *)instance;
- (id)buildStatusItem;

@end
```

### .m

```
#import "KBStatusMenu.h"

@implementation KBStatusMenu
static KBStatusMenu *gInstance = nil;

+ (KBStatusMenu *)instance 
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (gInstance == nil)
            gInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return(gInstance);
}

- (id)buildStatusItem 
{
    myStatusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]         statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];
    statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"statusNormTemplate.png"];
    [myStatusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [myStatusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [myStatusItem setMenu:myStatusMenu];
    return myStatusItem;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of your own, with `alloc` and `init`, and then replacing it with the shared `instance`?

Comment: Are you sure `myStatusMenu` actually exists? (I.e. is non-nil?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `myStatusMenu` as an outlet, but never loaded a nib (or assigned anything to it yourself). An outlet cannot get objects out of nowhere; the outlet is set only when you load a nib that has the outlet connected to something (or assign something to the variable yourself, as if it weren't an outlet).

You can prove this by adding a line to `buildStatusItem` that logs the value of the `myStatusMenu` instance variable. I expect that it will be `nil`.

What you need to do is:

1. Create a nib to contain the status item's menu.
2. Set the class of the File's Owner to `KBStatusMenu`.
3. In KBStatusMenu, implement `init` to load the nib you just created.

Then, by the time you reach `buildStatusItem`, loading the nib will have set the outlet, and you will have a menu to give to your status item.

I would recommend only creating one `KBStatusMenu` instance. In this case, I recommend enforcing the singleton: `init` should test whether `gInstance` has already been set and, if so, return that; only if it hasn't should it initialize and return `self`.

Comment: Yes, 'myStatusMenu' is nil! (Back to fixing.)

Comment: "1. Create a nib to contain the status item's menu"

- I had the status menu created inside MainMenu.xib

Comment: @janeh: That doesn't help, since KBStatusMenu has no way of knowing that. It isn't in the MainMenu nib and doesn't own the MainMenu nib. The application owns the MainMenu nib, and I don't think creating the KBStatusMenu in the MainMenu nib is right, hence my suggestion: Make a new nib for KBStatusMenu to own.